# Multi dimensional arrays: Declaraton and initialisation(Java)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

there

I have programmed in Java for about 4 years now. I was looking at a 2-D array and something caught my interest; the syntax.

So when declaring and initializing a 2-D array:

```
int [][] a = new int[2][3];
```

I know that I am creating an array of arrays of type int;

So how is type determined my first guess was that you have an array of type int [] i.e [] a is of type int []. I know that I am not expressing this well.

I'm trying to ask: Could someone explain the syntax in detail and explain which square bracket in declaration matches to which square bracket in initialization?

Sorry if my English is poor.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a 2D array you are basically making an array in another array so by doing: `int [][] a = new int[2][3];` You are declaring an array with a size of 2 containing arrays of integers with a size of 3. The number between the bracket indicates the size of both arrays.

Comment: I'm talking about a[] containing objects of type int[] and whether the int in the second square bracket in the initialization syntax is just short hand?

Comment: @rert588 The declaration is the same as saying: “I want an 2D array with this name” there is no array yet only a pointer when you say ‘= new  int [2][3]’ You are creating an array and pointing that pointer to it. Those brackets aren’t just some shortcut.

Comment: Not shortcut...shorthand. You could say " = new int[2][]"

Comment: Thereafter initialize each nested array in separate statements with varying lengths.

Comment: @rert588 You seem to understand the syntax fine. So what is your question then? Shorthand means " a method of writing rapidly by substituting characters, abbreviations, or symbols for letters, sounds, words, or phrases" according to: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shorthand which this is not because this is the only way to declare a 2D array.

Comment: This way is sufficient if you want to store data in a format that represents something that represents a rectangular matrix. This syntax can also be used:

Comment: int[][] a = new int[4][]; a[0] = new int[1]; a[1] = new int[1]; a[2]  = new int[3]; a[3] = new int[2]; I never left lines after each statement, if I press enter it posts the comment.

Comment: @rert588 Yes I know that is possible but your question is not clear to me anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139945/discussion-between-sjoerd-dal-and-rert588).

Answer (score 0):

When we write:

```
int iAmAnArray[][], iAmNotAnArray;

iAmAnArray = new int[2][3];
iAmNotAnArray = 13;
```

If you see the above code it clearly states that by using above style you can still declare normal variable along with the array variable, but when we write like bellow

```
int[][] iAmArray1,iAmArray2;

iAmArray1=new int[3][];
iAmArray2=new int[4][];
```

we can only declare array variable and one important thing is square bracket is not required for every variable, and is good approach when we have to declare or use too many variable of same type( say array).